# Can the flare gun be resupplied in BF1?

Tags: battlefield-1

I keep forgetting to see if this works. Will my flare gun resupply in the Support class drops an ammo crate?

Comment: I think yes, not sure though. Works for other gadgets.

Comment: this should be an answer, I verified it recently. I couldn't believe it, even grenades come back :)

Comment: Since this worked, please accept this with the green checkmark!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, all gadgets, ammo, and even explosives come back. Have fun with that (AIR) mortar!